# Unable to check into TFS and Build with Continuous Integration '

Tags: azure, tfs

I have an Azure Web application that I checked into TFS yesterday with no issues. Upon checking in, the resource manager will inject our nuget packages and deploy if it builds successfully.

I made a few changes (added a class) and checked in today. I received this error on the build: 
[image]

[image]

Here's the quote to help the future search bots:

> Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc unshelve Gated_xxxxxx;****** /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt'.

I looked into the log response, to see if I get more detail, but it says the exact same thing. I have not changed my password or username.

How can I debug this to figure out the issue?

**UPDATE**

To save others from the headache. The issue was that we had CI builds per project. A file from another project had snuck in as well. So I was checking in for 2 different projects on 2 different solutions (Which both go to the same TFS server). So make sure you only check in for that one project!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To save others from the headache. The issue was that we had CI builds per project. A file from another project had snuck in as well. So I was checking in for 2 different projects on 2 different solutions (Which both go to the same TFS server). So make sure you only check in for that one project!

Comment: Totally. I definitely pulled a few hairs on that one hah!

Comment: My Shelveset contained files located outside of root source directory for the build definition. Excluding those files from Shelveset fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: The visual studio was already 'exclude'ing the changes from other branch. I didn't notice & I was trying to include and check-in. Now I left it as is & checked-in .. and it worked

Comment: This is very strange. Why should the build rely on what was checked-in in a shelveset? It should just get the source code and build. In my situation, I just had to issue a new build.

Comment: Thank you, I really wish a more appropriate error message could be returned

Answer (score 2):

You can receive that error as well if you try to check in a file that is in a project that is not mapped in your build definition.

Let's say that you have a file named `FileA.cs` that is in a project named `ProjectA.csproj`. If you do changes in FileA.cs and this file is included in your changes, you need to map `ProjectA.csproj` in the Get source step of the build definition.

[image]