# TFS checkin is getting rejected where to find the mapping for the files in my pending changes

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and TFS
I have made some changes to an existing solution and now wanting to check in. When i checkin after about 6 seconds i get a build rejected with the following error

```
Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc unshelve Gated_2018-05-18_07.55.11.2589;HM-EU\abe.prakash /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt'.
```

After doing a little research I found that the error could be to do with mappings (link below).

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167274/get-sources-exit-code-1-returned-from-process-file.html

How do I check the mappings of the files which i have changed to see if they map correctly.

I have hovered over the file and saw that they have the accurate path where they are present in the solution also is there a detailed log which i can see instead of the build page (which opens up after clicking 'View build details')

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're trying to change a file that's not mapped in the workspace for your gated checkin build. You'll need to either

- Not change that file as part of the same changeset as something that's managed by a gated checkin
- Modify your gated checkin build definition to include a mapping to the file in question

Answer (score 1):

For the gated check-in, [A few other things to know](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers?view=vsts#a-few-other-things-to-know):

> Make sure the folders you include in your trigger are also included in
>   your mappings on the Repository tab.

So, make sure you only check in the changes for that **one project**, but not related to other projects which not mapped to the workspace during build.

More information you can reference this similar thread : [Unable to check into TFS and Build with Continuous Integration '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405685/unable-to-check-into-tfs-and-build-with-continuous-integration)